# Visual Studio testing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to do some unit testing within the IDE.

During the testing, the exposed service that is being tested is supposed to read from the configurationmanager - thus getting the connection string to the database.  This works in DEV and PROD.   But running under the MS unit test rig, it is not reading the configuration, thus i am getting a NULL reference exception.

I can go in and hard code the connection string, and it works fine -

but my question is....

Is there a way to identify, in the actual code that is being tested, that it is being tested, and use an alternate connection string (hard coded)?

It would seem to me, that a conditional define (i.e. #debug) would tell the compiler to use this instead of that kind of thing....

I'm sorry for the poorly written question, this unit testing rig stuff is new to me.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an app.config to your test project and put the connection string in that file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to ensure there is a config for the MS unit tests project - so the config settings end up in the folder where the MS unit tests are actually running.

However, I would recommend that you remove any database connectivity from your unit tests because unit tests should be testing business logic. Testing that involves connectivity with web services or databases are not testing logic.

Comment: Joe - I agree with your assertion of the database stuff - my unit tests are testing the web services portion of the code, and the unit tests are embedded in the project, so the tests call the webservices that are generated at the time the tests are run.   By adding the app.config, and copying the connection strings into the app.config file and place it within the test project, the web services are being called, and using the parameters needed.  Thank you